# Django Profiles

Tags: django

I am trying to setup Django to have profiles for authors. It needs to be a really simple solution and I have what I believe should work:

Model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class MyProfile(models.Model):
    "Extends the user object for custom attr"
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)
    websiteName = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    twitterHandle=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    bio = models.TextField()

    User.profile = property(lambda u: MyProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

Settings

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "btc_app.UserProfile"
```

However whenever I create a profile I get a type error:

> Exception Value:   coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, User
>   found

My post data looks like this

```
POST

website u''
bio u'tttt'
_save   u'Save'
twitterHandle   u''
user    u'2'
websiteName u''
csrfmiddlewaretoken u'5af9526bc84673fc3338d63272804b92'
```

There is a drop down with all the users in it and it lets me pick one but for some reason the save fails... Any ideas?

Thanks,
CG

Comment: Note: You don't need the `User.profile = ...` code. You can access the profile for a user by using the Django builtin method User.get_profile() that will return the registered profile model for a user. Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your unicode method you're returning an user instance, try something like

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username
```